# $A.getCallback not working

Tags: lightning-aura-components

```
component._resizeHandler = function (event) {
              console.log('resizing ....');
              $A.getCallback(function() {
                if (component.isValid()) {
                  console.log('valid')
                } else {
                  console.log('not valid')
                }
              });
          };

          window.addEventListener("resize", component._resizeHandler, false);
```

The code in $A.getCallback is not executing? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should pass the return value from $A.getCallback directly to the addEventListener method. Here is a demo app that stores the callback in an attribute if you need it later. If you don't need it later, you can inline it directly as a parameter.

```
<aura:application >
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
    <aura:attribute name="resizeCallback" type="Object" access="private" />
</aura:application>
```

---

```
({
    init: function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set('v.resizeCallback', $A.getCallback(function(){
            if(component.isValid()) {
                console.log('component valid');
            } else {
                console.log('component not valid');
            }
        }));
        window.addEventListener('resize', component.get('v.resizeCallback'));
    }
})
```

---

## Inlined

```
({
    init: function(component, event, helper) {
        window.addEventListener('resize', $A.getCallback(function(){
            if(component.isValid()) {
                console.log('component valid');
            } else {
                console.log('component not valid');
            }
        }));
    }
})
```

Comment: +1 but I would recommend storing the callback in a private attribute via `component.set("v.resizeCallback", $A.getCallback(...))`, since that seems to be the standard way of doing things. I did verify that giving the callback directly to addEventListener works.

Comment: @sfdcfox - Can you either edit my answer or add one of your own to include that? I am still getting my lightning/js legs and while I *think* I know what you mean I have never done that before or seen it done...Is the attribute type string? - And thanks for validating that it worked. It was actually one of your answer on another question that got me in that direction

Comment: No problem. I did a mockup, give me a few minutes and I'll put it in there.

Comment: @sfdcfox  If you don't need it later, you can inline it directly as a parameter. Can you give small description on this through small snippet of code ?? Thanks for this.

Comment: @user533 Sure. It means just wait it says on the tin; putting the method directly into the second parameter of addEventListener. Code included for your perusal.