# Lightning addEventListener to li

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript-controller

I'm trying to add an event listener anytime something inside of a **li** is clicked, but I'm having issues with it.

Component

```
<aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}" />
<li class="slds-item" aura:id="fullCmp">

</li>
```

Controller

```
doInit: function(component, event, helper)
{
    var cmp = component.find("fullCmp");
    alert('cmp = ' + cmp);
    cmp.addEventListener("click", function(){
        alert('Hello World');
    });
}
```

When I print out the component, I get:

```
cmp = SecureComponent: markup://aura:html {4:30a}{fullCmp}{key: {“namespace”:”c”}}
```

My page then throws an error:

```
cmp.addEventListener is not a function
```

How can I successfully add an event listener to the **li**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you have more than one `<li>` item for this answer.

You need to run this code in the renderer (or use the newly added event for Summer 17 - we'll use the renderer for now as production code does not support this yet.

Helper:

```
addListeners : function (component){
  var cmp = component.find("fullCmp");
  cmp.forEach(function(item){

      item.getElement().addEventListener("click", function(){
        alert('Hello World');
      });
  });        
}
```

Renderer:

```
afterRender: function (component, helper) {
    var afterRend = this.superAfterRender();

    helper.addListeners(component)
    return afterRend;
},
```

Don't call the code from the controller init function at all - at this point, the dom is not ready and your components have not rendered yet - hence your error.

For the single component version, replace my forEach with your version.

The event for Summer 17 is `aura:valueRender`

```
<aura:handler name="render" value="{!this}" action="{!c.onRender}"/>
```

Ref [here](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_lightning_event_render.htm?edition=&impact=):

**EDIT** Note - if you are going to be doing anything framework specific, you also need to read this answer which follows on from mine - it shows you how to use `$A.getCallback` with this answer. [Here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/166873/a-getcallback-not-working).

Comment: Just to know, which new Summer 17 event are you talking about ?

Comment: updated the answer for you - aura:valueRender is the new event

Comment: aura:valueRender documentation is here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/aura:valueRender/documentation

Answer (score -3):

There is one quick fix for this issue, instead of writing **afterRender** method you can use events on your HTML i.e **onchange** event

```
<li onchange="someAction();"></li>
```